# Bootstrap Select on Mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a form drop-down which passes the value to change the div which is displayed below. This all works great on a desktop, however I cant get the drop-down to drop when using a mobile device.

The drop-down color changes when I click, however there is no option list that drops down.

My code is:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
                <label>Please Select a Package Option</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="package_option" id="package_option">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                    <option value="the_single">The Single</option>
                    <option value="the_duo">The Duo</option>
                    <option value="the_trilogy">The Trilogy</option>
                    <option value="the_custom">The Custom</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason why your drop down change color when clicked because you use the `disabled` on your select tag. 
try to use this on your select class `col-md-6 col-sm-12`.

more information about grid system in bootstrap is [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)